# SDKBOX Unable to login into facebook on an android device

Tags: android, facebook, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've used SDKBOX to integrate facebook in my cocos2dx project but I am unable to login into facebook on android device. I think I am missing a minor thing. Can somebody help me on this? 
Ps I have so far managed to login and share on ios devices  but when i try to do the same thing on android i face issues.

Cocos2dx 3.9
Latest Sdkbox.
Device Nexus 4.

Android Manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

<application hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">


    <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="cocos2dcpp" />

    <activity android:configChanges="orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" /><meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1602801803302391" android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" />

</application>

<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AndroidManifest.xml` seems fine.

Could you please check **Manual Integration For Android and Android Studio** section in this [link](http://docs.sdkbox.com/en/plugins/facebook/v3-cpp/) and make sure that all things are there for you ?

Best,
Pabitra

Comment: public class AppActivity extends Cocos2dxActivity.AppActivity has nothing in it.

Comment: it will be blank only.
but have you checked the link !!
if you follow that it should solve your issue.